# How Can I override Sales_Order_History template in customer section at frontend

Tags: template, sales-order, customer-account

I am creating custom module for RMA(product return) in magento that's why I am trying to add a custom link "Return Request" in My Orders panel in customer account section as shown in below image-
[image]

For that I have created module "Assel_Rma" which have some files as below-

**config.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config>
  <modules>
        <Assel_Rma>
            <version>1.0.2</version>
        </Assel_Rma>
   </modules>
   <frontend>
        <routers>
            <rma>
                <use>standard</use>
                <args>
                    <module>Assel_Rma</module>
                    <frontName>rma</frontName>
                </args>
            </rma>
        </routers>
        <layout>
            <updates>
                <rma>
                    <file>assel/rma.xml</file>
                </rma>
            </updates>
     </layout>
    </frontend>
    <global>
        <models>
            <rma>
                <class>Assel_Rma_Model</class>
            </rma>
        </models>
        <blocks>
            <rma>
                <class>Assel_Rma_Block</class>
            </rma> 
            <sales>
                <rewrite>
                    <sales_order_history>Assel_Rma_Block_Sales_Order_History</sales_order_history>
                </rewrite>
           </sales>               
        </blocks>
        <helpers>
            <rma>
                <class>Assel_Rma_Helper</class>
            </rma>
        </helpers>
    </global>
</config>
```

**frontend/base/default/layout/assel.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout version="0.1.0">

    <sales_order_history translate="label">
        <label>Customer My Account Order History</label>
        <update handle="customer_account"/>
        <reference name="my.account.wrapper">
            <action method="setTemplate">
                <template>rma/sales/order/history.phtml</template>
            </action>
          <block type="customer/account_dashboard" name="customer.account.link.back" template="customer/account/link/back.phtml"/> 
        </reference>
        <reference name="left">
            <remove name="catalog.shopby"/>
            <remove name="basenews"/>
            <remove name="bestsales"/>
            <remove name="left-block-banner-free"/>
            <remove name="blogleft" /> 
        </reference>
    </sales_order_history>

</layout>
```

**app/code/local/Assel/Rma/Block/Sales/Order/History.php**

```
<?php
class Assel_Rma_Block_Sales_Order_History extends Mage_Sales_Block_Order_History
{
}
```

After doing all above now "My Orders" looks like as below-

[image]

In above image my sidebar gets doubled and nothing is shown on the page.
can anyone please help me to get rid out of this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change rewrite code in xml

```
<sales>
                <rewrite>
                    <order_history>Assel_Rma_Block_Sales_Order_History</order_history>
                </rewrite>
           </sales>
```

you have to set template from block as it is set in `Mage_sales_Block_Order_History`.

```
public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->setTemplate('rma/sales/order/history.phtml');

        $orders = Mage::getResourceModel('sales/order_collection')
            ->addFieldToSelect('*')
            ->addFieldToFilter('customer_id', Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomer()->getId())
            ->addFieldToFilter('state', array('in' => Mage::getSingleton('sales/order_config')->getVisibleOnFrontStates()))
            ->setOrder('created_at', 'desc')
        ;

        $this->setOrders($orders);

        Mage::app()->getFrontController()->getAction()->getLayout()->getBlock('root')->setHeaderTitle(Mage::helper('sales')->__('My Orders'));
    }
```

Comment: thanks for the reply @ Qaisar..I have added that _construct() function in my block file but no luck even I have cleared cache.

Comment: did you remove it from xml?

Comment: Sorry but what I need to remove from xml.?

Comment: when you set it from block what you need xml for? do it from one place

Comment: Ok. I removed code from xml so now sidebar comes only once but page still show empty.

Comment: did you copy the history.phtml and then modify that? and also enabled template hint to check the your html file are there? an also check for error log what error you are getting..

Comment: Ok I checked system.log file and found this error-
CRIT (2): Not valid template file:frontend\base\default\template\rma/sales/order/history.phtml  but I am not sure from where I am getting this error.?

Comment: $this->setTemplate('rma\sales\order\history.phtml'); add it like that

Comment: I have added $this->setTemplate('assel/rma/sales/order/history.phtml'); and it worked but this time only page title is being shown only and order table is not being shown. I think $_orders->getSize() is not working in my history.phtml file.

Comment: copy all block function too..

Comment: I have copied all block functions but same problem exists.

Comment: Just set template only in construct and check

Comment: I have remove all codes from within _construct() except this $this->setTemplate('assel/rma/sales/order/history.phtml'); still no luck

Comment: Do I need to copy all Helper, models files and controllers file from mage/sales/order to my module? but I don't think it should be.

Comment: in my history.phtml file there is code $_orders->getSize() in which I am not getting anything.

Comment: No need of that may be something missing

Comment: It is for count you can use count for that

Comment: I checked by var_dump($_order) and not getting anything even not null. By the way I have only one file on my Block folder i.e. history.php is there need to add some other file here if I am missing something.

Comment: No need for anything else

Comment: I am getting this error in log file Undefined variable: _orders

Comment: wait le me try this and check where we are getting worng

Comment: the error was with ur rewrite code i updated the question follow it

Comment: I have corrected it already but no luck

Comment: Copy the comstruct function and change template

Comment: sorry did not get you what should I do.?

Comment: In my answer copy the comstruct function in ur block only no more other than that change the template as u required

Comment: I have copied your contructor function and only changed the template path to 'assel/rma/sales/order/history.phtml'  in my block file but no luck

Comment: OK. I founded my fault. did mistake in copy paste. now it worked fine.

Comment: Now when I have added a custom product return link on history.phtml page then how can I create new page for this new link.?

Comment: New controller action for that

Comment: I have placed that link as <a href="<?php echo $this->getRmaUrl($_order) ?>"><?php echo $this->__('Return Request') ?></a>
this code shows url http://abcd.com/sales/rma/order_id/54  but after clicking on it it redirects to 404 page at frontend while in my controller i have setup its template file as 
$block = $this->getLayout()->createBlock('core/template'); $block->setTemplate('assel/rma/sales/order/rma.phtml');
echo $block->toHtml();

Comment: You have to create controller first. Search for that i will answer you tomorrow now here 2 am.